# With D3, can I identify the coordinates of an animated element on a line path at a specific point?

Tags: svg, d3.js

[Zak's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5630/zac) question and answer about [How to animate an object along a GeoJSON path using d3.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794501/how-to-animate-an-object-along-a-geojson-path-using-d3-js) is an example of how to make a circle move along a path generated by d3.svg.line():

```
// via Zak's fiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/5m35J/6/

duration = 10000;
circle.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .ease("linear")
    .attrTween("transform", function (d, i) {
    return function (t) {
        var p = pathNode.getPointAtLength(pathLength*t);
        return "translate(" + [p.x, p.y] + ")";
    }
});
```

With reference to this code, it possible to know when, in a given frame of an animation, the circle has reached the a specific point on the line? How would I identify when the circle has passed over a specific coordinate that makes up the line, e.g.:

```
[-75.195794106, 43.092815735,"140.7"]
```

thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503151/in-d3-how-to-get-the-interpolated-line-data-from-a-svg-line or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431595/how-do-i-return-y-coordinate-of-a-path-in-d3-js